# Double quotes are appearing in XML declaration after an XSLT transformation instead of single quotes

Tags: xml, xslt

In my java program I'm using below XSLT code for transforming xmls :

`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[descendant::text() or descendant-or-self::*/@*[string()]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[string()]">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`

This is performing the required transformations correctly but it is changing the XML declaration by inserting double quotes `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` instead of this original single quotes `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>` 
I was wondering how can I retain those single quotes in my formatted xmls !

Comment: Those two declarations are exactly the same XML, so it isn't changing anything.

Comment: @jon-hanna I understood that but I have strict java code transformations in place after the response is getting formatted.That's why I wanted to retain the single quotes. isn't there any way of doing this ?

Comment: @SaurabhBhoomkar, what kind of "strict java code transformation" is that? If you are processing XML with XML tools then they certainly don't complain about the quote characters in an XML declaration being double quotes. The XSLT processor does not retain any quote characters, neither those in the XML declaration (that is not even part of its data model) nor those in XML attributes, it parses the XML input with an XML parser into an input tree, transforms that into a result tree and serializes the result tree.

Comment: Sounds like your "strict java code transformations" are too strict, because they are requiring a particular subset of XML to be used. That's very poor practice.

Answer (score 2):

XSLT processors generally do not provide control over the quotes used by its results serializer.

But regardless, the difference does not matter in XML.  XML processors, tools, and libraries will not care about `'` vs `"` surrounding attribute values, and neither should you.